# Calculate daily average for selected period in PHP

Tags: php, datetime

I would like to calculate the average for the same days (e.g. Monday, Tuesday, etc) in a selected period:

```
$data = array(
    '2016-05-01' => 100, 
    '2016-05-02' => 150, // monday
    '2016-05-03' => 5,
    '2016-05-04' => 5,
    '2016-05-05' => 25,
    '2016-05-06' => 25,
    '2016-05-07' => 25,
    '2016-05-08' => 25,
    '2016-05-09' => 55, // monday again
    '2016-05-10' => 25,
    '2016-05-11' => 35,
    '2016-05-12' => 25,
    '2016-05-13' => 125,
    '2016-05-14' => 25,
    '2016-05-15' => 225,
    '2016-05-16' => 25, // and again...
    '2016-05-17' => 25,
    '2016-05-18' => 25,
    '2016-05-19' => 25,
    '2016-05-20' => 25,
    '2016-05-21' => 25,
);

// Store occurrence of same days 
$countDays  = array('Mon' => 0, 'Tue' => 0, 'Wed' => 0, 'Thu' => 0, 'Fri' => 0, 'Sat' => 0, 'Sun' => 0);

// Store values
$output = array('Mon' => 0, 'Tue' => 0, 'Wed' => 0, 'Thu' => 0, 'Fri' => 0, 'Sat' => 0, 'Sun' => 0);

// Count days
foreach($data as $key => $value) {

    $dayName = date('D', strtotime($key));

    $countDays[$dayName]++;
}

// Calculate average
foreach($data as $key => $value) {

    $dayName = date('D', strtotime($key));

    $output[$dayName] += round($value / $countDays[$dayName]);
}
```

For example, I'd expect the following output for all the available (three) Mondays:

> (150 + 55 + 25) / 3 = 230 / 3 = 76

Comment: Is the program running slow? I'm not seeing any way to really optimize the code. Trying to see if maybe dropping one of the loops. But can't find a great way of doing it that will improve the code.

Comment: You can add the qty of data in output in the same for each as the 'countdays' and that way avoid doing another entire loops

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only change I would make is in your two `foreach` loops. If you see below, I have made the change I would recommend making. This will make the loop a bit shorter and more accurate.

```
// Store occurrence of same days 
$countDays  = array('Mon' => 0, 'Tue' => 0, 'Wed' => 0, 'Thu' => 0, 
     'Fri' => 0, 'Sat' => 0, 'Sun' => 0);

// Store values
$output = array('Mon' => 0, 'Tue' => 0, 'Wed' => 0, 'Thu' => 0, 
     'Fri' => 0,'Sat' => 0, 'Sun' => 0);

// Count days
foreach($data as $key => $value) {

    $dayName = date('D', strtotime($key));

    $countDays[$dayName]++;
    //add up all the qty when you go through the array the first time
   // IE all the Tuesdays in the array get added up.
    $output[$dayName] += $value;
}

// Calculate average
foreach($output as $key => $value) {
    //now take all the totals you just made in the other loop, and avg them
    $output[$key] = round($value / $countDays[$key]);
}
```

This is the only way I can see to improve the code. This way, you have a 'shorter' second `foreach` loop, which may improve the speed of your code a bit. You could also do the `$value` by reference and change it on the fly, but I think the way I have it now is clearer. This way you aren't doing the math more then once per array element, so you only do the avg for something like Tuesday once.

As Pinoniq stated you can drop the second foreach loop and add a function, and use array_map to do the rounding. Leave the first foreach loop the same and then add this, instead of the other foreach loop.

```
function average($a, $b){
    return round($a/$b);
}
$output = array_map("average",$output,$countDays);
//var_dump($output); //<-only if you want to test results.
```

Downside: You lose your index keys if you do it like this. However, you can easily fix that by just keeping the keys in an array, and then print them out at the same time, or use `array_combine($keys,$values);` to get your output array back.

Comment: I've edited your revision comment to state the change that was made, instead of keeping it in the post.

Comment: maybe use array_map and array_reduce functions instead.

Comment: @Pinoniq I will look those two functions up and see what they do. Thanks for the advice.

Answer (score 2):

Your `foreach()` loop calculating the average is certainly not what you are looking for:

```
foreach($data as $key => $value) {
    $dayName = date('D', strtotime($key));
    $output[$dayName] += round($value / $countDays[$dayName]);
}
```

What you do here is something like this:

$$
average = \sum_{i=1}^n \lfloor { value_i \over n } + 0.5 \rfloor
$$

In other words, your code says that you do a division and immediately round the results then sums those rounded numbers.

When what you are asking is to get this instead (from your formula shown below your code):

$$
average = \lfloor { { \sum_{i=1}^n value_i } \over n } + 0.5 \rfloor
$$

One solution is to use Caperneoignis suggested changes (which will certainly be the fastest.)

Another way is to add yet another loop (at least that should make it clearer how the math is affected as shown in my formulae):

```
// your existing loop do the sum
foreach($data as $key => $value) {
    $dayName = date('D', strtotime($key));
    $output[$dayName] += $value;
}

// compute the average
foreach($output as $dayName => $value) {
    $output[$dayName] = round($value / $countDays[$dayName]);
}
```

Comment: Your missing the word 'like' right after your first code segment. I'm not yet allowed to make edit suggestions. So letting you know by comment.

Comment: @Caperneoignis, I also noticed that my second loop was going to repeat the division `n` times for each value... It would give the right result, but speaking of optimization...

Comment: I thought it looked a bit weird when I saw it this morning. Since I was half asleep, I only paid attention to the none code portion. Don't feel bad, I had ````+=```` on my second foreach loop to find the average, and took me a solid hour before I noticed, I wouldn't produce the right output. lol